# how to download sbt plugins from nexus?

Tags: scala, sbt, nexus

I'm running into an issue with getting plugin dependencies from my corp nexus. Specifically, it seems the resolver for addSbtPlugin is looking for the scala version and sbt version in the path but I can't find a way to specify that in the nexus artifact upload options.

I have the following plugins defined in my plugins.sbt:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
```

I also have the following .sbt-repositories file which i am using for repository configuration:

```
[repositories]
  nexus1: https://nexus.somecorp.com/nexus1/content/repositories/central/content/
  nexus2: https://nexus.somecorp.com/nexus2/content/repositories/central/content/
```

I run sbt like so:

```
sbt run -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.repository.config=.sbt-repositories
```

All of my regular library dependencies download fine, however the sbt plugins added via addSbtPlugin do not - they are looking for a path to the artifact that doesn't exist (scala version and sbt version).

For example:

```
[warn] module not found: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.3.8
[warn] ==== nexus1: tried
[warn] https://nexus.somecorp.com/nexus1/content/repositories/central/content/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.3.8/sbt-plugin-2.3.8.pom
```

Doesn't work, because the correct path to the pom file should be:

```
https://nexus.somecorp.com/nexus1/content/repositories/central/content/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.3.8/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13-2.3.8.pom
```

I also tried adding a specific resolver to my .sbt-repositories file using ivy's parameters:

```
nexus1: https://nexus.somecorp.com/nexus1/content/repositories/central/content/, [organization]/[module]_[scalaVersion]_[sbtVersion]/[revision]/[module]_[scalaVersion]_[sbtVersion]-[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

But that didn't work either, for two reasons:

1. [organization] resolves to ex. com.typesafe.play which doesn't fit with nexus's com/typesafe/play
2. I even tried hard coding the organization values but then sbt complains that the pom file for the artifact doesn't match with the sbt and scala version (haven't found a way to specify those things in nexus or in a pom file)
3. .[ext] resolves to .xml for ivy

How do I use sbt plugins with nexus being my repository?

In case it matters, I'm using sbt 0.13 and have read through the sbt documentation several times now to try and resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

to your `plugins.sbt`. Also remember that each line needs to be separated by two newlines in `.sbt` files.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help as I need the sbt plugins to download from nexus, and then we reach the same problem as above...

Comment: Maybe a `Plugin.scala` and check in the code that's required to use your custom repos?

Comment: any chance you know of docs related to getting sbt to respect my plugin.scala + still use addSbtPlugin?

Comment: It's the same as any other `.scala` build file. You're basically specifying the meta meta project.

Comment: will look into it and report back... meanwhile, i got a recommendation to setup nexus with an ivy proxy